# How can you use Tuple elements as keys in a Mapped Type or template literal in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tuples, template-literals, mapped-types

Are there any incantations to properly type the following function in typescript?

> given a function `createMap()` that takes:
>
> - a prefix (e.g. `foo`)
> - and a tuple of suffixes (e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'])
>
> calling `createMap('foo', ['a', 'b', 'c'])` return the following mapped type:
>
> ```
>   {
>     a: 'foo.a',
>     b: 'foo.b',
>     c: 'foo.c',
>   }
> ```

The function implementation is pretty straightforward, but the return type doesn't seem to be:

```js
const createMap = <P extends string, S extends string[]>(prefix: P, suffixes: [...S]) => {
  return suffixes.reduce((map, suffix) => ({
    ...map,
    [suffix]: `${prefix}.${suffix}`,
  }), {});
}
```

I know this is incorrect, but it would naively look something like `{ [K in S]:` ${P}.${K in S} `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a *mapped type* to compute the return type of the function. We only need to map over the elements in `S` by computing the union `S[number]`. Each element `K` can now be used to concatenate the prefix `P` with a *template literal type*.

```
const createMap = <
  P extends string, 
  S extends string[]
>(prefix: P, suffixes: [...S]) => {
  return suffixes.reduce((map, suffix) => ({
    ...map,
    [suffix]: `${prefix}.${suffix}`,
  }), {}) as { [K in S[number]]: `${P}.${K}` }
}

const result = createMap('foo', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
//    ^? const result: { a: "foo.a"; b: "foo.b"; c: "foo.c"; }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBZZAHGBeGAPAAoyIAeaYAJhDNPAJZgDmANDAMqkWLW31NmAbQC6APgAUWJADMGZAFwwi7CAFcZcsoghKhAOkMcRASjxiYAbwBQMGEihr4YOhq079SKmuCIJEgFtsVTd5M1wLCRs7O0N9IKxWWxihdU15ESUAAwASS2lELQBffTy04qykuyKTdksamGRaSxghAGkYJk4hMDUAgCNEeBFMmFzLIhK8tqKsmCLrBetQSFgkdQAbWHwEFDRMLAkAchkQECP2ISPkC5gj-tuj4CPTawB6N5iYAD0AfjhwNB7Do1FslC1kEoAESnED6ZBQgDcMH60Nh+n6SLgaLO+mAWKKQA)

Comment: Ah ha! I was missing the `S[number]` for the iteration on `[K in S[number]]`! 

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve it you must set the list `as const`

then you can do the following:

```
type CreateMap = <S extends string, A extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(s: S, a: A) => {
  [K in (A extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : never)]: `${S}.${K}`
};

const createMap: CreateMap = (s, a) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(a.map(key => [key, `${s}.${key}`])) as any
}

const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const

const res = createMap('foo', list)
```

You can see an example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCBZRYoF4oB4DKUEAHigHYAmAzlFcHAJZkDmANFAIJGkSU0BKSCgHsyAGxAc4cRCFx1GLAHxKAFFQBcUfO0RaOASmxKoAbwBQUKAG0A0lCZRVXEuWpRBiEeMnTZuJgAzCDgoAFUTAH5wqC0yCAA3EIMAXS0AAwASU3wAXwA6bNtc9PNcgG5zcwBjUTooaoRkNAwteCQUdEwcdV0jLBMLKwRgAFc4MigAeQAjACsIauB8wLhhAFsAUTJ6BggqVUR89YxVAGsIEGMbC5B2LNMqAuzbkpSDI0QaRDIQMqramR6mIGPUcNYAOSICHsCEzGFQCHVCEpKBfBp1YAAzFQBA0HCNDotMCqCGBYTCBEgugGcxAA)